# Scanning film (negatives) on Linux

Tags: manjaro, scanner, sane, hp

I'm trying to scan 35mm film strips using a HP Scanjet G3010 and XSane on Manjaro Linux (17.0.2). Unfortunately, XSane is slow and doesn't work quite right.

Eg. I can choose between 600 or 1200 DPI (nothing in between), but if I choose 1200, the process can run for 20 minutes and not finish (I've killed it after that long). On the other hand, 600 DPI is too low of a resolution.

I'm pretty sure the printer supports higher DPIs, as I've used it with HP's software on Windows, and it worked perfectly.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there anything I can do to make XSane run normally? Can I manually change the resolution in some config file or something?
2. If not, is there any other free, open source software that I could use?

I'd like to avoid using a VM, and haven't had any luck with Wine (trying to run HP's software).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SANE backend for the G3010 is marked as "basic, unmaintained", so that is probably a dead end (unless you're prepared to dig in the source code).

For scanners, the only viable non-free solution is Vuescan, which you can test before use.

sorry.

Comment: Aaah, okay. Haven't found that information. Thank you.